# Integration tests - error when connecting to the database

Tags: magento2, database, testing, integration-test

I'm having trouble running the magento2 integration tests.

I followed the documentation and set up the database parameters in `install-config-mysql.php` :

```
'db-host' => 'mysql:3306',
'db-user' => 'magento2_test',
'db-password' => 'test_user_password',
'db-name' => 'magento2_test',
```

And when I run phpunit, I get the following:

```
PHPUnit 6.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

S.R.......PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: Port must be configured within host parameter (like localhost:3306 in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:393
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(861): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1189): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quote('sequence_order_...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2626): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->showTableStatus('sequence_order_...', NULL)
#3 /var/www/html/dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Db/Sequence.php(58): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->isTableExists('sequence_order_...')
#4 /var/www/html/dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Application.php(420): Magento\TestFramework\Db\Sequence->generateSequences()
#5 /var/www/html/dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Application.php(436): M in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 393

=== Memory Usage System Stats ===
Memory usage (OS):      605.15M (100.86% of 600.00M reported by PHP)
Estimated memory leak:  5.15M (0.85% of used memory)
```

My database runs in a separate container linked to the website container. I can connect to mysql from the website container using cli.

That error seems odd since the port is indeed configured within the host parameter.

I have disabled the memory limit in my phpunit.xml with this line given in the documentation

```
<ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
```

What could be wrong with my setup ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to set my database container ip instead of 'mysql' in the `db-host` parameter.